# Name for an overhead monitor dashboard

Tags: hardware

The scenario: A group of technicians use a large, overhead monitor to view their workflow around products to pick, combine, and pack. The monitor displays a dashboard with a list of orders and order statuses on it. This helps the technicians understand cutoff times, upcoming tasks, and so on.

Is there a better term for this device than "overhead dashboard" or "overhead monitor"? Is there anything specific to inventory management?

Comment: Overhead monitor inventory dashboard describes the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the term "workstream monitor" used for displays that shows the status of the pipeline. Also "data (visualization) panel", and even fancier names like "business intelligence panel" or "BI Panel" also start to pop up if there are charts and diagrams involved.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further research, "digital status board" seems to be the term that is used in the marketplace. "Digital production board" is also used.